# hide popup windows while executing os.system cmd

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I convert my `py-script` to a *.exe-file, so I am executing It as *.exe

the problem Is while executing the cmd commands using `os.system`
cmd/black windows shown for a `millisecond` then gone!

B1 B4 and B5 don't shows popup windows...! but they don't change anything/not working, not changing the registry value...!

only B2 and B3 are working...! but they are showing the cmd window...!

here's my edited example...!

myapp.py

```
from tkinter import *
import os, subprocess

# Main
root = Tk()
root.title("MyApp")
root.geometry('300x300')

def cbtn1():
    subprocess.check_output('cmd /c reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MySoftware" /v myvalue /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f >nul 2>&1')

def cbtn2():
    os.system('reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MySoftware" /v myvalue /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f >nul 2>&1')

def cbtn3():
    os.system('cmd /c reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MySoftware" /v myvalue /t REG_DWORD /d 00000003 /f >nul 2>&1')

def cbtn4():
    subprocess('reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MySoftware" /v myvalue /t REG_DWORD /d 00000004 /f, shell=True')

def cbtn5():
    command = 'reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MySoftware" /v myvalue /t REG_DWORD /d 00000005 /f >nul 2>&1'
    subprocess.check_call(shlex.split(command),stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)

btn1 = Button(root, text="B1", height=1, width=10, command=cbtn1)
btn1.pack(side=TOP)

btn2 = Button(root, text="B2", height=1, width=10, command=cbtn2)
btn2.pack(side=TOP)

btn3 = Button(root, text="B3", height=1, width=10, command=cbtn3)
btn3.pack(side=TOP)

btn4 = Button(root, text="B4", height=1, width=10, command=cbtn4)
btn4.pack(side=TOP)

btn5 = Button(root, text="B5", height=1, width=10, command=cbtn5)
btn5.pack(side=TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

---

- How can I hide the popping up windows?

---

I am using:

```
Python v3.6.0 on Windows 7 32bit - auto-py-to-exe
```

Comment: above code It's just an example...!

Comment: Are you selecting "Windows Based" in the "Console Window" selection? If you are and the problem is still occurring, then consider using `subprocess.check_output(command)` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `os.system`. What happens if you remove the `cmd` from your command? I think it is unnecessary and probably what's causing the window to open

Comment: Don't use `os`. Use `subprocess` instead with the `shell=True` argument.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid supports Monica you'r right the "cmd /c" It's unnecessary ...!

Comment: @SyntaxVoid supports Monica also I tried "subprocess.check_output" but It's seems not to be work..!

Comment: @Mike - SMT unfortunately no...!

Comment: I tried using subprocess with shell=True argument but seems not to be work...!

Comment: @SyntaxVoid supports Monica ofcourse am using "Windows Based - Single File" methods am using a GUI Auto Py To Exe...!

Comment: Just to provide some feedback on your example you only really need to show us one button with one function to reproduce your issue. That is how you should write your Minimal Reproducible Example. That said are you sure you are using subprocess correctly? I have the same problem you did on Windows and the solution was to use subprocess. Though I didnt use "py to exe" I used "freeze".

Comment: @Mike - SMT, am sorry about this, but the overflow was threating me about closing the question If I did't edit IT...! so that's reason I edit my post and extend the exmaple code...! also I want to make question more clearfully...! I just want to hide the popping windows...!

Comment: @Mike - SMT, really am not sure If I did wrong on my code or If am using the subprocess correctly..!

Comment: Well you have a mistake for `shell=True`. You have it inside of the quotes. It is a separate argument. So it should look like this: `subprocess.call('reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MySoftware" /v myvalue /t REG_DWORD /d 00000004 /f', shell=True)` where the shell is its own argument.

Comment: finally got rid of popping up windows...! so as you see the question was duplicate am sorry about that case am still beginer...! thanks for everything @Mike - SMT, and SyntaxVoid supports Monica